# Sonarqube Unrecoverable indexation failures: 1 errors among 1 requests. Check Elasticsearch logs for further details

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to run sonarqube to scan a java project against localhost. However, when I run mvn sonar:sonar I get this error `Unrecoverable indexation failures: 1 errors among 1 requests. Check Elasticsearch logs for further details`. It asks me to look for an ElasticSearch file, which doesn't seem to be on my machine as when I look at the Sonarqube home directory this is what I see.

[image]

This is my pom configuration:

```
<jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.8.7</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
<sonar.version>3.9.0.2155</sonar.version>

<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>sonar</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <!-- Edit this URL for sonarQube server -->
                <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000/</sonar.host.url>
                <sonar.login>myToken</sonar.login>
                <!-- Sonar-JaCoCo properties -->
                <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
                <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        
 <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
                <sonar.web.accessLogs>true</sonar.web.accessLogs>
                <java.version>17</java.version>
                <sonar.exclusions>**/entity/**</sonar.exclusions>
                <sonar.test.exclusions>src/test/**/*</sonar.test.exclusions>
            </properties>
        </profile>
```

And here what I see when I type `sonar -v`

`/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sonarqube/9.8.0.63668/libexec/bin/macosx-universal-64/sonar.sh`

Thank you.

*Update*

Adding the outpute for /var/log

[image]

Comment: "It asks me to look for an ElasticSearch file, which doesn't seem to be on my machine." - No it doesn't.  It asks you to look at the **log files**.

Comment: The location of the log files will depend on your logging configs.  But if you haven't changed the default logging configs, they will probably be in "/var/log/elasticsearch/" based on what I've seen.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I've updated the post with a screenshot for what I see under /var/log. And no, I haven't changed any configs (at least not intentionally) as I only did the straightforward brew sonarqube installation.

Comment: Ah.  OK.  It is sonar + es.  According to https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup-and-upgrade/troubleshooting/, you should look for `es.log` in your <SONARQUBE_HOME>/logs` directory.

Comment: Yes, I was on that page before, but as per my first screenshot there are no logs file under the Sonarqube home directory.

Comment: I tried looking for it using `ls -al` as well, but it makes no difference.

Comment: Well ... maybe you should run something like `sudo find / -name es/log\* | less` to try to find the file.  Or try and find the logging config file itself and see what it says.  Note that the config file could be embedded in a JAR file.

Comment: Tried that but couldn't find this file.

Comment: I found this question here https://community.sonarsource.com/t/java-lang-illegalstateexception-unrecoverable-indexation-failures-1-errors-among-1-requests-check-elasticsearch-logs-for-further-details/54746/2 which seems similar to what I'm trying to do, but I don't fully understand how it get resolved.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the find command.  It should have been `sudo find / -name es.log\* | less`.   But like I said, if you can't find the log file, look for the logging config file that says where the log file should be and what it filename is.

Comment: Thank you! That worked now. I was then able to find these logs under /System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/var/sonarqube/logs/es.log

Comment: There I saw the error "flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded" and by navigating to /System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/var/sonarqube/data and deleting the es7 folder after stopping sonarqube I was able to start it again and it worked once I rerun my scan.

Comment: If you'd like to turn your comment into an anwwer I can upvote it and mark it as accepted. Thanks very much again.

Comment: If you type `man find` you should be able to figure out what that `find` command actually does.  The `find` command is a very useful investigative tool ... and worth taking the time to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "It asks me to look for an ElasticSearch file, which doesn't seem to be on my machine."

Actually, it asks you to look at the log files(!)

The default name for SonarQube's elastic search log file is `es.log`.  If you can't find it in "obvious" places (e.g. in the "/var/log" tree on a Linux system), you should be able to find the log file using the `find` command; e.g.

```
 $ sudo find / -name es.log\* | less
```

If that doesn't find the log file, you will need to look at your SonarQube installation's logging configuration to figure out where log4j is writing the file.

Once you have found the log file, read what it says.  Note that there is information in the [SonarQube Troubleshooting](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup-and-upgrade/troubleshooting/) on common elastic search problems.

Comment: Just copying here what I saw and how I fixed the issue after looking at the content of the log file: There I saw the error "flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded" and by navigating to /System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/var/sonarqube/data and deleting the es7 folder after stopping sonarqube I was able to start it again and it worked once I rerun my scan.